# In-App Review doesn't show up in Internal Test Track

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, google-play-core

I can only get the review prompt to show up once, even when in internal test track, in order for it to show up again I need to clear data and cache of the Google Play Store.
I meet all of the testing requirements since I have another game which I'm using In-App Review and everything works correctly on that one.
No errors show up when logging.

I'm using the unity version of the plugin, here are some of the things I've tried and their results:

- Popup works every time in the Internal App Sharing, submit button is greyed out since it wasn't downloaded from the store.
- Clearing storage and cache from Google Play makes the review appear once, but it doesn't have the correct settings, even though it was downloaded though the internal test track, the comment is tagged as optional, and when trying to publish said review, either including the comment or not, it always gives the following error: DF-DFERH-01 Server Error
- I've also tried multiple versions of the plugin, mainly 1.6.1, 1.7.0, and 1.8.0, without success on any of them (I did update proguard every time).
- I also tried resolving dependencies with other versions of the External Dependencies Manager, .172 and .174, both without success.
- I've tried another account also included in the internal test track, didn't work
- On another game I published, the In-App Review works as intended, I'm using the exact same code.

What's weird to me is that it works correctly on the Internal App Sharing, the app is currently on Open Beta, while the other game which In-App Reviews work correctly is on production, but I doubt that's related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to confirm that this is an issue on Google's side, after releasing the game to production, the popup started showing up on the Internal Test Track every time while using the same version as before.

To anyone that is also having this issue, **if the In-App Review works on Internal App Sharing, you should be safe to release it to production** and the issue will fix itself.

I can't say for sure this will work for everyone, but it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

After passing the real machine test, project A only released the internal test version, and did not release the PRD version. After the comment, an error was reported:

> 05-23 11:00:23.794 14480 14536 E Volley : [1874] hvw.a: Unexpected response code 500 for https‍://play-fe.googleapis.com/fdfe/addReview?doc=xxxx&title=&content=&rating=5&itpr =false&rst=1&dff=1
> 05-23 11:00:23.857 14480 14480 E Finsky : [2] xrw.b(1): Error posting review: network time: 0, HTTP status code: na, exception DisplayErrorMessage[Error retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01]

Without changing any code, replace the package name and google-service.json of project A with the package name and google-service.json of project B (published PRD version), project A can comment normally, and comments can be seen in the background of project B information.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the issue can be related to the **Google Play Store cache**, delete it.